# How to set the list element at guess_row, guess_col to "X"?

Tags: python

I might be having some trouble understanding arrays.

This is how I did it. It is incorrect I know but why?

```
guest_row = [X]
guest_column = [X]
```

How should I set a list element at guess_row, guess_column to X?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some nested list, like

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

then you need

```
array[guest_row][guest_column] = 9
```

Say `guest_row = 1` and `guest_column = 0`. Then `array[guest_row]` is the second item in `array`, `[4, 5, 6]`. That makes `array[guest_row][guest_column]` the first element of the second element of `array`, currently occupied by `4`. The above assignment changes that value, so that `array` now looks like

```
[[1, 2, 3], [9, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```